# Shell timeout does not stop cloudfoundry app-nozzle, there is still new output

Tags: bash, shell, timeout, cloud-foundry

I would like to run a CloudFoundry app-nozzle command for 10 seconds to gather some metrics about an application. Even though I stop the command, there is still new output in the output file afterwards. I have no idea what is happening.
My command (that would be run inside a script):

```
timeout 10s cf app-nozzle my_app --filter ContainerMetric > CF_nozzle.txt
```

It looks that it stopped and exited in Git Bash, I can run other scripts, even after minutes there are new lines in the file. I closed the whole window, and it is still ongoing.

Update: I tried it in CLI only and after the timeout it still emmits data even to command line.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this might be a bug in Windows Git bash. The same command works well in Ubuntu terminal.